# Integration Output Doesn't make sense

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to calculate the integral of a voltage pulse. I have designed this circuit to do the integration. I am using a non inverting integrator:

[image: Schematic]

The op_amp_2 is the voltage pulse. Comp_1 is used to discharge the cap once the pulse has ended. So that the integral of each pulse can  be found.

This is how the output looks like:

[image: Waveform]

I wonder why the output falls down as the pulse ends. Is this because of the bias current of Op-AMP? I am specifically using a low bias (~pA) current opamp.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: What do you think R8 is doing?

Comment: Because your circuit ain't an  integrator?

Comment: R8 is used to set the opamp output DC operating point.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Why do you say so? This is a non-inverting integrator..

Comment: An integrator has no DC bias, no DC operating point. Where did you get the concept of this?

Comment: R8 discharges C2 over time, so this circuit is a high pass, not an integrator.

Comment: @Janka thanks for the comment. Rf was causing the leakage and the circuit was not behaving as integrator, after removing it, I see a linear rise in voltage until the switch discharges the cap.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that might be worth mentioning is that it's not an actual integrator that you got there. It may mimic one and fool you.

Here's a schematic of how an actual integrator would look like. Also, look at the size of the "R8" I'm using. It's 100 kΩ here, not 1 kΩ. 1 kΩ is way too small.

[image]

As you can see, I'm simply integrating a square wave, the *actual integrator* shows a triangle wave, as it should. While the bottom "*integrator"* which you are using show a triangle wave on top of the square wave input.

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+49.687244006919805+50+5+50%0Aa+1216+352+1312+352+1+15+-15+1000000+-4.5003853283904494e-7+0%0Aw+1216+368+1216+416+0%0Aw+1312+352+1312+416+0%0Aw+1312+416+1376+416+0%0Ar+1136+416+1216+416+0+10000%0Ag+1216+336+1216+352+0%0Aa+1040+416+1136+416+0+15+-15+1000000+0.0000249995000099998+0%0Ag+1040+432+1040+448+0%0Ar+976+400+1040+400+0+10000%0Aw+1040+400+1040+352+0%0Ar+1040+352+1136+352+0+10000%0Aw+1136+352+1136+416+0%0Aw+1312+560+1376+560+0%0Aw+1312+496+1312+560+0%0Aa+1216+496+1312+496+1+15+-15+1000000+2.499974514184529+2.4999999999999996%0Ac+1216+560+1312+560+0+0.000001+-0.048607032895428226%0Aw+976+400+976+480+0%0Aw+1216+512+1216+560+0%0Ar+1136+560+1216+560+0+10000%0Ag+1136+560+1136+576+0%0Aw+976+480+1216+480+0%0Ac+1216+416+1312+416+0+0.000001+-0.04500430332243733%0AR+976+400+928+400+1+2+100+2.5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+1216+416+1216+448+0%0Ar+1216+448+1312+448+0+100000%0Aw+1312+448+1312+416+0%0Aw+1312+592+1312+560+0%0Ar+1216+592+1312+592+0+100000%0Aw+1216+560+1216+592+0%0Ax+984+535+1185+538+4+24+Your%5Cs%22integrator%22%0Ax+1037+308+1278+311+4+24+An%5Csactual%5Csintegrator%0Ao+3+64+0+4098+1.25+0.00009765625+0+2+3+3%0Ao+12+64+0+4098+5+0.00009765625+0+2+12+3%0A) in case you want to simulate it and see for yourself.

---

To make this *answer* appear less as a comment. The reason for why your output voltage is drooping is because of R8. Your small capacitor (only 1 nF) is discharging through a very small resistor (R8).

And to answer the title "Integration Output Doesn't make sense", well that's because it's not proper integration as I proved above with the circuit simulation.

Comment: The circuit you showed as my integrator is not correct. You don't have the R and C filter on the non inverting pin matching with the R and C of the inverting pin.

Comment: @Ash If that's what you want to believe. Believe that.